# How do I customize ads in my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ads

I'm building an ios app that target special type of people, so I did implement adMob in my app but the problem adMobs shows ads depends on location if user allow. 
What I'm looking for is to show ads that is of my app type ?

For example,if my app was a gaming app so I would only show adds for gaming apps or anything related to gaming or if my app is educational i would show only ads related to education.

I hope someone knows the way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys I found the Answer in their website after long digging

Here it is:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150235?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google AdMob [official document](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#choose_an_ad_format) say:

> The Mobile Ads SDK is now imported and initialized, and you're ready
>   to implement an ad. AdMob offers a number of different ad formats, so
>   you can choose the one that best fits your app's user experience.

Implement customize ads to access following link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start